# JQuery append() DIV HTML without <img>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Been trying to find an answer to this but can't seem to get my head around it:

```
var newLayout = '<div id="blog-left"></div>' ; // This creates the layout the content will be moved to
    newLayout += '<div id="blog-right" class="nivoSlider"></div>' ;
    newLayout += '<div style="clear:both;"></div>' ;
    newLayout += '<div id="img-temp" style="display:none;"></div>' ;

$('.blog').append(newLayout); // Add the new layout

$('#blog-left').append( $('.blog p') ); // All <p>'s being added to the new layout
$('#blog-right').append( $('.blog img') ); // All <IMG>'s being added to the new layout
```

This work really well, however the problem I have is instead of appending the `<p>` to `#blog-left` I want to append all the contained `HTML` but minus the `<IMG>` tags. So all `HTML` goes into `#blog-left` and `<IMG>`'s go into #blog-right.

I've tried using `.html()` which works to a point but the `#blog-left` & `#blog-right` are in the containing div `.blog`.

I've tried a couple of things but nothing returns correctly if at all. So do any of you bright sparks have the solution using JQuery?

Thanks in advance.

Sam T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like so:

```
var $blog = $('.blog');

// first add all images to right (removes them from .blog)
var $right = $('<div id="blog-right" class="nivoSlider" />')
              .append($blog.find('img'));

// add all remaining elements from .blog to left
var $left = $('<div id="blog-left" />').append($blog.children());

var container =  '<div style="clear:both;"></div>' + 
                 '<div id="img-temp" style="display:none;"></div>';

// add the new content to .blog
$blog.append($left).append($right).append(container);
```

Comment: Thats fantastic, this was what I was after. I kept tried different versions of this yesterday but was getting my code in a muddle :). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to filter out img tags.

```
var $blog = $('.blog');
$blog.append(newLayout);
var $p = $blog.find("p");
var $img = $blog.find("img");
$('#blog-left').append($p);
$('#blog-right').append($img);
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/ZVNmN/1/).